# What databases support UNION JOINs?

Tags: sql, database, union-join

First of all, this item is like a curiosity to me.

I was writing some code for a utility library and was adding methods to run different kinds of SQL join statements. All good, but at some point I came across the obscure `UNION JOIN` clause included in the SQL-92 spec (page 179).

I don't know how useful it can be (I never used it) and it's implemented (AFAIK) in HyperSQL only.

For the record, here's how it works. If we have two tables T and U with any numbers of colums/rows:

```
====== T =====       === U ===

   a    b    c          d    e
---- ---- ----       ---- ----
   1    2    3         10   11
   4    5    6         12   13
```

Then:

```
select * from T union join U
```

Produces (in no particular row order):

```
   a    b    c    d    e
---- ---- ---- ---- ----
   1    2    3 null null
   4    5    6 null null 
null null null   10   11
null null null   12   13
```

Anyway, I wanted to know which databases do actually support it, or if you have seen it in the wild.

I was thinking about also asking what it can be good for, but I don't want this question to be closed as "Primarily Opinion Based".

Comment: Isn't that the same as `OUTER UNION`?

Comment: @Tom Wow, that's another implementation. Not quite standard, but yeah.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In theory, **ANY** SQL supports it

As documented in ["SQL Problems and Solutions" by Moiseenko](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/en/book_explicit_join_operations/page3.html):

> This join type have been introduced in SQL-92 language standard, but disappeared in later versions of SQL standard. Particularly, it is absent from SQL2003 (ANSI and ISO). As many other structures of SQL, UNION JOIN is excessive because it can be expressed as substraction of full outer join and inner join. Formally, we can write this expression as follows:

```
A UNION JOIN B :=
(A FULL JOIN B)
EXCEPT
(A INNER JOIN B)
```

> If DBMS does not support FULL JOIN (MySQL), it can be obtained via union of left and right outer joins. So our formula takes the form

```
A UNION JOIN B :=
((A LEFT JOIN B)
UNION
(A RIGHT JOIN B))
EXCEPT
(A INNER JOIN B)
```

In practice, SAS supports it, at least version 9.3. Ref: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sqlproc/63043/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0o4a5ac71mcchn1kc1zhxdnm139.htm

Comment: . . I'm impressed.  I thought I had memorized the 92 standard way back when, and this does not ring a bell at all.

Comment: Thanks, that's another database that supports this archaic SQL clause. Your explanation makes a lot of sense. This SQL clause looks like a superfluous construct.

Comment: I have seen unsupported assertion that MariaDB supports the clause, but couldn't find any evidence in documentation so far.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - Memorizing that standard would be quite a feat, given that it's over 600 pages (http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt).

Comment: @dcp . . . My team was writing a database at the time and we had to know all the nuances.

Comment: Ocelot RDBMS was supporting this type of join (UNION JOIN); It was developped by Peter Gulutzan that joined the MySQL team there is about 20 years ago... https://www.ocelot.ca/ocelot.htm